# filteredselectmultiple chosen value added to database but not showing in chosen field in django

Tags: django-views, django-forms, django-templates, django-admin-filters

``I have project using django admin filterselectmultiple I saved data to database from listbox1 but after rendering template saved data not show in listbox2, also I required to add or remove data from database, Please possible to help me.
[attached Image for Filterselectmultiple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CB0Ky.png)
**template**

```
       <div id='frame'>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <div id='sk_body'>
                <fieldset>
                <legend>Fill required fields</legend>      
                    <form>
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <table>
                            {{ form.media }}
                            {{ form.as_table }}
                            <script type="text/javascript" src="{% url 'jsi18n' %}"></script>
                        </table>
                            <input type="submit" value="Count">
                    </form>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>  
                        
                
            
        
Veiw.py
def index(request):
    item=savemodule.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DrgCalculator(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            choosen_drg = form.cleaned_data['drg_choise'] #result as QuerySet
            #choosen_drg_list = list([str(i) for i in choosen_drg]) #you can convert it to list or anything you need 
            for i in choosen_drg:            
                d=savemodule(DrgModel=i) 
                d.save()   
            return render(request, 'index.html')
           
        context = {
            'form': form,'item':item
            }
        return render(request, 'index.html', context)
    
    else:
        form = DrgCalculator()
       
    context = {
        'form': form,
        }
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```